# неразрешенный внешний символ C++/ VS 2017

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

### Делаю все по сайту [Создание расширения C++ для Python](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/python/cpp-and-python).

В части "Преобразование проекта С++ в расширение для Python":
**Не могу собрать проект, тк ошибки:** LNK2001 у __imp__PyFloat_FromDouble, __imp__PyFloat_AsDouble, __imp__PyModule_Create2. И в итоге ошибка LNK1120.
Помогите разобраться с ошибкой!
**Вот код:**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>    

const double e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527;

double sinh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 - pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

double cosh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 + pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

//double tanh_impl(double x) {
//  return sinh_impl(x) / cosh_impl(x);
//}
PyObject* tanh_impl(PyObject *, PyObject* o) {
    double x = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
    double tanh_x = sinh_impl(x) / cosh_impl(x);
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(tanh_x);
}
static PyMethodDef superfastcode_methods[] = {
    // The first property is the name exposed to python, the second is the C++ function name        
    { "fast_tanh", (PyCFunction)tanh_impl, METH_O, nullptr },

    // Terminate the array with an object containing nulls.
    { nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr }
};
static PyModuleDef TanhBenchmark_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "TanhBenchmark",                        // Module name
    "Provides some functions, but faster",  // Module description
    0,
    superfastcode_methods                   // Structure that defines the methods
};
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_TanhBenchmark() {
    return PyModule_Create(&TanhBenchmark_module);
}
```

Вот скрин ошибок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Примечание:
В части "Создания основного проекта С++" в пункте 7 предположительно две ошибки:

1. Забыли указать тип принимаемого аргумента "**х**". Я написал **double x**.

2. При исправлении этой ошибки возникает другая: **С2169** у **tanh**. **Возможное решение:** переименовать tanh в tanh_impl. Ну и так же вместо sinh и cosh напишем sinh_impl и cosh_impl.*

Comment: Скорее всего вы забыли подключить нужные библиотеки в проекту, т.е. lib-файлы.

Comment: а как исправить ошибку? В свойствах проекта в пункте добавлено: Дополнительные каталоги библиотек : C:\Program Files\Python36\libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Проверьте что Python36.lib указана для компоновки, свойства проекта: Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies
2. Проверте что в папке C:\Program Files\Python36\libs действительно находится указанная библиотека.
3. Если первые два пункта выполняются, то нужно еще раз убедится, что версия и сборка вашей Python36.lib именно та, которая вам нужна.
4. Если вы уверены что в ваша Python36.lib правильня, то нужно сообщить об ошибке тому, у кого вы его взяли.

Comment: в папке C:\Program Files\Python36\libs находятся файлы: "python36.lib", "python3.lib", "_tkinter.lib", "libpython36.a". Там нет "Python32.lib". Что тогда делать?.. В доп зависимостях(Additional Dependencies) нет "Python32.lib".

Comment: Очевидно надо использовать *python36.lib*.

Comment: спасибо, помогло. Думал что 32 обозначает битность